# Console Worker Follow-Up

Tags: c#, console

A few hours ago I posted a [similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133963/consoleworker-update-console-timer-with-how-long-application-has-been-open) but this is a **follow-up**, I have revised the code and added and removed certain lines of code and hopefully improved it a bit, I just brought it here for a final cleaning, can anyone notice anything than can be improved even more? Some of the code has been totally changed such as the way I wrote the uptime string

```
var consoleTitleString = string.Format("{0} / {1}, {2}, and {3}", 
                    projectName, 
                    serverUptime.Days + " day" + (serverUptime.Days != 1 ? "s" : ""),
                    serverUptime.Hours + " hour" + (serverUptime.Hours != 1 ? "s" : ""),
                    (StaticSettings.includeSecondsInUptimeString) ? serverUptime.Minutes + 
                    " minute" + (serverUptime.Minutes != 1 ? "s" : "") + " and " + 
                    serverUptime.Seconds + " second" + (serverUptime.Seconds != 1 ? "s" : "") : 
                    serverUptime.Minutes + " and minute" + (serverUptime.Minutes != 1 ? "s" : "")
                    );
```

I feel its a bit squeezed in, is there a way to make it a bit more clean without the need of an if statement?

Just a few of the improvements I've made

- Removed field comments
- Improved long-lined code
- Removed useless code

```
using Faze.Other.App;
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Faze.Other.Util.Console
{
    class ConsoleWorker : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Timer consoleWorkerTimer;
        private readonly int consoleWorkerInterval;
        private readonly ILog classLogger;

        public ConsoleWorker()
        {
            consoleWorkerInterval = 1000;
            classLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ConsoleWorker));
            consoleWorkerTimer = new Timer(timerElapsed, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(consoleWorkerInterval), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(consoleWorkerInterval));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the timers callback once elapsed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timerObject">ConsoleWorker timer's object.</param>
        private void timerElapsed(object timerObject)
        {
            var serverInfo = Faze.getServer().getServerInformation();

            if (serverInfo.hasStarted())
            {
                if (StaticSettings.advancedLoggingWhenDebugging && Debugger.IsAttached)
                    classLogger.Info("ConsoleWorker has elapsed -> " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

                TimeSpan serverUptime = DateTime.Now - serverInfo.getStartedTime();

                var projectName = serverInfo.getProjectName();

                var consoleTitleString = string.Format("{0} / {1}, {2}, and {3}", 
                    projectName, 
                    serverUptime.Days + " day" + (serverUptime.Days != 1 ? "s" : ""),
                    serverUptime.Hours + " hour" + (serverUptime.Hours != 1 ? "s" : ""),
                    (StaticSettings.includeSecondsInUptimeString) ? serverUptime.Minutes + 
                    " minute" + (serverUptime.Minutes != 1 ? "s" : "") + " and " + 
                    serverUptime.Seconds + " second" + (serverUptime.Seconds != 1 ? "s" : "") : 
                    serverUptime.Minutes + " and minute" + (serverUptime.Minutes != 1 ? "s" : "")
                    );

                System.Console.Title = consoleTitleString;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            consoleWorkerTimer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**One final thing,** Someone on the old post said use CamalCase because I would seem like I'm coding JavaScript otherwise, is this a do do and a don't don't go against thing or is that just his personal preference?

Comment: Have you ever seen any method or property that starts with a small letter in the .net Framework?

Comment: Many, most source codes that I have worked with, but is that unusual?

Comment: Yet it is... See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx this is the direct link to the capitalize section.

Answer (score 2):

I still find the string creation awful. If you cannot use C# 6 the I suggest the `StringBuilder`:

```
var consoleTitle = new StringBuilder()
    .Append(projectName).Append(" / ")
    .Append(serverUptime.Days).Append(" day".Pluralize(serverUptime.Days))
    .Append(serverUptime.Hours).Append(" hour".Pluralize(serverUptime.Hours))
    // ... 
    .ToString();
```

and an extension method to get rid of conditionals:

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Pluralize(this string text, int value)
    {
        return (value != 1 ? text + "s" : text)
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you work the ternary in there, or would you use an if statement in the way it was previously done in the other posts?

Comment: well, it's in the example. you put it an extension instead of repeating it several times.

Comment: I meant when the op is switching between displaying seconds and not displaying seconds

Comment: @Malachu It's just a sample and the thing with the optional seconds isn't anything that couldn't be easily solved or wasn't solved yet. I never said the example was complete. You are very picky :-P

Comment: I was just curious what you thought about that and how you would solve that issue, it is one of the things that the OP brought from their previous posts into this one, the question of how to handle that "switch"

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce nesting you could perform an early return at the beginning

```
if (!serverInfo.hasStarted()) return;
```

I really feel like you are trying to golf this code and it is making it really hard to read

You really should break out all the variables that you are using to build this string and build them then use String Interpolation or String.Format.

The main reason I say this is because you have a lot going on in the different pieces of the string.

Here is what I would do, so that I can see what is going on, I wouldn't try to shorten this up like you are doing because it looks messy, this is my opinion only.

```
private void timerElapsed(object timerObject)
{
    var serverInfo = Faze.getServer().getServerInformation();

    if (!serverInfo.hasStarted()) return;

    if (StaticSettings.advancedLoggingWhenDebugging && Debugger.IsAttached)
        classLogger.Info("ConsoleWorker has elapsed -> " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

    TimeSpan serverUptime = DateTime.Now - serverInfo.getStartedTime();

    var projectName = serverInfo.getProjectName();
    var daysString = string.Format(serverUptime.Days + " day" + (serverUptime.Days != 1 ? "s" : ""));
    var hoursString = string.Format(serverUptime.Hours + " hour" + (serverUptime.Hours != 1 ? "s" : ""));
    var minutesString = string.Format(serverUptime.Minutes + " minute" + (serverUptime.Minutes != 1 ? "s" : ""));

    var consoleTitleString = projectName + " / " + daysString + " " + hoursString + " " + minutesString;

    if (StaticSettings.includeSecondsInUptimeString)
    {
        consoleTitleString += " and " + serverUptime.Seconds + " second" +
                              (serverUptime.Seconds != 1 ? "s" : "");
    }
    System.Console.Title = consoleTitleString;           
}
```

The only way that I think you should shorten this anymore is by creating another method that will build your strings based on the specified time piece that you pass into it.

---

Other than that I like the rest of the changes that you made to your code.

Answer (score 0):

**consoleWorkerInterval - consts Vs readonly**

Currently you've got this as a readonly int, that you're initialising in the constructor.  This value doesn't need to be set for every instance of the class, you already know it at compile time.  Instead you could set it up either as a static readonly field:

```
private static readonly int consoleWorkerInterval = 1000;
```

Or a const one:

```
private const int consoleWorkerInterval = 1000;
```

**timerElapsed - Naming convention**

It's unusual to see methods that start with a lowercase letter in C#.  Even private methods would typically follow Pascal [naming convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx), so I would expect the method to be called `TimerElapsed`.  Your public methods/properties/fields should always be following the naming guidelines, which methods on the objects you're calling like `getServer` and `getServerInformation` clearly aren't.

**ConsoleTitle**

All those ternary operators does make the title generation code look a bit messy.  The first thing I'd suggest doing is extracting the section that formats the a value's output with or without the 's' in a similar way to the method suggested by [@t3chb0t](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/133979/4203).  However, I'd build this on top of the StringBuilder class.  I'd then add another method that is responsible for formatting a whole `TimeSpan`, which uses the extension method to ensure the correct 's'ness.  Because you want to only format seconds if they're required, a third extension method might be useful to achieve this.  Putting it all together you could end up with a class like this:

```
static class StringBuilderConsoleExtensions
{
    internal static StringBuilder FormatForTitle(this StringBuilder sb, TimeSpan timeSpan, bool includeSeconds)
    {
        return sb.FormatForTitle("{0} day", timeSpan.Days)
                 .FormatForTitle(", {0} hour", timeSpan.Hours)
                 .FormatForTitle(", and {0} minute", timeSpan.Minutes)
                 .OnlyIfTrue(includeSeconds, s => s.FormatForTitle(" and {0} second", timeSpan.Seconds));
    }

    internal static StringBuilder FormatForTitle(this StringBuilder sb, string format, int value)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat(format, value);
        if (1 != value) sb.Append('s');
        return sb;
    }

    internal static StringBuilder OnlyIfTrue(this StringBuilder target, bool condition, Func<StringBuilder, StringBuilder> funcToRun)
    {
        if (condition) return funcToRun(target);
        return target;
    }
}
```

Putting all of this together, means that the `timerElapsed` method is a lot more manageable:

```
public  void timerElapsed(object timerObject)
{
    var serverInfo = Faze.getServer().getServerInformation();

    if(!serverInfo.hasStarted())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (StaticSettings.advancedLoggingWhenDebugging && Debugger.IsAttached)
        classLogger.Info("ConsoleWorker has elapsed -> " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

    TimeSpan serverUptime = DateTime.Now - serverInfo.getStartedTime();

    System.Console.Title = new StringBuilder().AppendFormat("{0} / ", serverInfo.getProjectName())
                                              .FormatForTitle(serverUptime, StaticSettings.includeSecondsInUptimeString)
                                              .ToString();
}
```

This is a fair bit more code than just using `if` to break up your logic, however each bit has a more distinct role in the process of building up the string.